# pm2 process not starting again after using ```pm2 stop index.js```

Tags: javascript, pm2

Ive been trying to fix this problem and havent found much of anything to help me with this. I used `pm2 stop index.js` from my cmd and now its staying as disabled. I tried disabling watch mode but that didnt do anything. This might be something really stupid but i dont know.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try stopping with the id

```
pm2 stop 0
```

Then start with the command

```
pm2 start --name <NAME> <PATH>
```